# Change owner of a currently running process

Tags: linux, shell, process, centos6

I have a process that is currently running with *pid*, `$PID`, and owned by the *user* `foo` which is **not root**. I want to transfer the ownership of this process to another *user* `bar` which is also **not root**.

Is there a shell command that changes the owner of a process? I'm thinking of a `chown` but for processes that looks something like.

`chownproc [option] PID`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428920/changing-the-owner-of-an-existing-process-in-linux) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140884/change-user-owner-of-process-on-mac-linux) are similar, but not quite what I'm looking for and `chown` man pages doesn't say anything about processes, only files.

If there isn't, is there a reason why this hasn't been done or isn't possible?

Comment: I've never heard of such mechanism.  The security implications are dramatic — the process opened the files and other resources using ID `foo`; should any of those be allowed to ID `bar`?  This is probably one of the main reasons why it is not done.

Comment: No user-level programs can do that. You need to write a kernel module to do that. e.g., https://github.com/xuancong84/supgroup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that, there's no such syscall. However, depending on how you want to affect the process, you could try some hack if the process is not critical to your system.

```
(gdb) attach process_id
(gdb) call putenv ("UID=1234")
(gdb) call putenv ("EUID=1234")
(gdb) call putenv ("GID=1234")
(gdb) detach
```

Note that this WILL NOT WORK:

```
(gdb) call setuid(1234)
```

This does not really answer to your question (change the owner of a running process), but considering that you may want to change the owner to affect something about the process, maybe this hack help.

Remember that it's very likely that this breaks your process.

(based on this: 
[Is there a way to change another process's environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables))

Answer (score 1):

Now, it is possible to do this at the kernel level.

This is actually a design flaw of the Linux kernel, that credential changes occur only on disks but not in memory. To put it specifically, when credentials (UID, GID, or supplementary group list) are changed, all existing processes will continue to use their previous credentials and enjoy access to previously granted data. And there is not a single API function to propagate credential change throughout the system (i.e., all processes). As a result of this defect, no user-level programs can do what you want. You have to end your current process and create a new process.

Nevertheless, at kernel level, it is possible to do this. I have just tried to make one and it works on simple programs. (https://github.com/xuancong84/supgroup)

However, in general it is not a good idea to do so because in general a program can have lots of external interactions, e.g., opened file handles, child processes/threads running on other CPU cores, bound pipes, opened devices, etc. Thus, changing the UID/GID while running can lead to many undefined behavior among which some can cause error (e.g., broken pipe, aborted I/O communication), some can turn out hazardous (e.g., system crash). I have tested that this program works on simple programs (such as `nc -l 8080`), but on a much bigger complex program running many threads on many CPU cores and GPU CUDA cores, having heavy network activity and disk I/O activity, I am not sure what will happen.