# Elevate privileges of running process

Tags: linux, bash, privileges

Is there a way for one process (such as an executable or bash script) to elevate the privileges of another, running, process? e.g. If I have a program running as normal user `user`, is it possible for another process, running as `root` to elevate the privileges of the first as if it had been run as root originally?

I have seen [exploits](https://labs.f-secure.com/assets/BlogFiles/mwri-mmap-exploitation-whitepaper-2017-09-18.pdf) modify the credential struct of a process to perform this, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do this more legitimately.

Looking further into this, it appears that there is no way to do this without installing a kernel module; essentially a rootkit. The kind of thing I want is demonstrated [here](https://0x00sec.org/t/kernel-rootkits-getting-your-hands-dirty/1485).

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Is this what you attempt to do? [Change owner of a currently running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401774/change-owner-of-a-currently-running-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but only at Ring 0, using the `commit_creds(prepare_creds(0))`, which will update the task struct associated with the userland process, setting UID/GUID to 0. This is only possible with code already running in Ring 0, such as a Kernel module/rootkit or kernel exploit. An example of how this may be done is [here](https://0x00sec.org/t/kernel-rootkits-getting-your-hands-dirty/1485).

Answer (score 8):

No, these properties of a process cannot be altered after it starts.

Comment: In this paper (https://labs.f-secure.com/assets/BlogFiles/mwri-mmap-exploitation-whitepaper-2017-09-18.pdf) a vulnerable kernel driver is used to edit a processes own cred struct, in order to execute a shell as the superuser. Is there no legitimate way to recreate this?

Answer (score 5):

**No.**  The only way to elevate a process’s privileges is by `exec`ing a setuid binary (such as `/usr/bin/sudo`); you can’t do it to an already running process.

You can, however, ask sudo to copy a file to a temporary path, launch your editor with your own privileges on the temporary path, and then copy the result back in place as root:

```
sudo -e filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start a new process using `sudo`, but starting a new instance with higher permissions will always result in a new process being created.
It's not possible to grant additional permissions to an already running process.